# spark to_date function - how to convert 31-DEC-98 to 1998-12-31 not 2098-12-31

Tags: apache-spark, str-to-date

(Py)Spark to_date convert 31-DEC-98 to 2098-12-31. Is there a way to make it 1998-12-31?

The document does not have an option to select 1000 or 2000.

- [to_date](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#to_date)

> to_date(date_str[, fmt]) - Parses the date_str expression with the fmt expression to a date. Returns null with invalid input. By default, it follows casting rules to a date if the fmt is omitted.

```
grade_type = spark.read\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .option("nullValue", "")\
    .option("inferSchema", "true")\
    .csv("student/GRADE_TYPE_DATA_TABLE.csv")

grade_type.show(3)
-----
+---------------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|GRADE_TYPE_CODE|DESCRIPTION|CREATED_BY|CREATED_DATE|MODIFIED_BY|MODIFIED_DATE|
+---------------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|             FI|      Final|  MCAFFREY|   31-DEC-98|   MCAFFREY|    31-DEC-98|
|             HM|   Homework|  MCAFFREY|   31-DEC-98|   MCAFFREY|    31-DEC-98|
|             MT|    Midterm|  MCAFFREY|   31-DEC-98|   MCAFFREY|    31-DEC-98|
+---------------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

```
grade_type = spark.read\
    .option("header", "true")\
    .option("nullValue", "")\
    .option("inferSchema", "true")\
    .csv("student/GRADE_TYPE_DATA_TABLE.csv")\
    .withColumn("CREATED_DATE", to_date(col('CREATED_DATE'), "dd-MMM-yy"))\
    .withColumn("MODIFIED_DATE", to_date(col('MODIFIED_DATE'), "dd-MMM-yy"))

grade_type.show(3)
-----
+---------------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|GRADE_TYPE_CODE|DESCRIPTION|CREATED_BY|CREATED_DATE|MODIFIED_BY|MODIFIED_DATE|
+---------------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
|             FI|      Final|  MCAFFREY|  2098-12-31|   MCAFFREY|   2098-12-31|
|             HM|   Homework|  MCAFFREY|  2098-12-31|   MCAFFREY|   2098-12-31|
|             MT|    Midterm|  MCAFFREY|  2098-12-31|   MCAFFREY|   2098-12-31|
+---------------+-----------+----------+------------+-----------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Spark 3.0, a new dates parser was introduced, with a changed behavior for dealing with 2 digits year.
You could find a reference for the change under [Upgrading from Spark SQL 2.4 to 3.0](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-migration-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-24-to-30)

`spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'LEGACY')` will give you the original behavior with the required results

---

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark.conf.set('spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy', 'LEGACY')

(spark.createDataFrame([('31-DEC-98',)], 'my_date string')
 .select(F.to_date('my_date','dd-MMM-yy')
 .alias('my_new_date')).show()
)
```

---

```
+-----------+
|my_new_date|
+-----------+
| 1998-12-31|
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I think you have to do some ugly string manipulation:

```
 df.withColumn("MODIFIED_DATE", 
               to_date(concat(col("MODIFIED_DATE").substr(0, 7), 
                              lit("19"),
                              col("MODIFIED_DATE").substr(8, 2)
                             ), "dd-MMM-yyyy"))
```

I get this (note: using Scala, but the API should be the same as PySpark):

```
scala> val df = Seq(("31-DEC-98")).toDF("MODIFIED_DATE")
scala> df.withColumn("new_date", to_date(concat(col("MODIFIED_DATE").substr(0, 7), lit("19"), col("MODIFIED_DATE").substr(8, 2)), "dd-MMM-yyyy")).show
+-------------+----------+
|MODIFIED_DATE|  new_date|
+-------------+----------+
|    31-DEC-98|1998-12-31|
+-------------+----------+
```